# What are the hinged(?) structures in front of the F-4 Phantom's intakes?

Tags: feature-identification

What are the large flat structures on the sides of the F-4 Phantom directly in front of the engine air intakes? They are more or less square, and may be hinged vertically.

Comment: Neither the answer here nor the alleged duplicate is complete. In addition to the assembly being a splitter plate, the hinged component is part of a variable intake ramp, used to optimize the intake geometry in order to get good pressure recovery at different mach numbers. This innovation significantly increased the top speed. https://digital.library.unt.edu/ark:/67531/metadc283785/m1/37/

Answer (score 1):

From Wikipedia:

> A **splitter plate** is a component in some jet aircraft, used to control the airflow into the engine. Where the engine air intake is mounted partway back along the fuselage or under the wing, the splitter plate diverts the boundary layer away from the engine intake. It is a form of boundary layer control.

[image]

**From Youtube: an F4**

[image]